# Big O for constant time complexity

Tags: algorithm, data-structures

If I have constant time complexity like c1+c2+c3 then I know that it will take linear time. I want to express it in terms of big O notation. If time complexity is f(n)= 2n+3 then we write O(n) then prove that f(n) < cg(n), but for constant time how would we do that?

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: Your first sentence seems to be contradictory. Is it constant or is it linear?

Comment: I want to know that if f(n)=C1+C2+C3 where c are constants then timw complecity will bhi O(1) but how to prove that using big oh notation

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you know that the time complexity of an algorithm is the combination of some constants like c1 + c2 + c3, then you can define a function f(x) = c1 + c2 + c3 = c. Then, using the definition of big O, which is

> f(x) = O(g(x)) as x goes to infinity
>
> if and only if there exists a positive real number M and a real number x0 such that
>
> |f(x)| <= Mg(x) for all x >= x0

we can say that f(x) = c is O(1) with g(x) = 1. The reason is that we can fulfill the requirements of the definition above by choosing M to be constant c and x0 doesn't matter here since the time complexity does not depend on the value of x.

Answer (score -1):

Constant time complexity is O(1).

Comment: This should be a comment; it's a matter of clarification.

Comment: I know it is O(1) but how to prove using big oh.